Unable to access DynamicFields
I have create a callable class that return dynamic fields.
public class DynamicField {
    @InvocableVariable
    public String key;

    @InvocableVariable
    public String value;

    public DynamicField(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public with sharing class GBCall {
@InvocableMethod(label='Call API' description='Calls API and returns dynamic key-value pairs')
public static List<List<DynamicField>> callAPI(List<APIRequest> requests) {
    List<List<DynamicField>> responses = new List<List<DynamicField>>();

    for(APIRequest request : requests) {
        try {
            String endpoint = xxx

            String requestBody = xxx

            HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
            httpRequest.setEndpoint(endpoint);
            httpRequest.setMethod('POST');
            httpRequest.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            httpRequest.setBody(requestBody);

            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest);

            if(httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(httpResponse.getBody());
                Map<String, Object> resultData = (Map<String, Object>) jsonResponse.get('result');
                List<Object> dataList = (List<Object>) resultData.get('data');

                if(dataList.size() > 0) {
                    for(Object record : dataList) {
                        Map<String, Object> recordMap = (Map<String, Object>) record;
                        List<DynamicField> dynamicFields = new List<DynamicField>();

                        for(String key : recordMap.keySet()) {
                            dynamicFields.add(new DynamicField(key, String.valueOf(recordMap.get(key))));
                        }

                        responses.add(dynamicFields); 
                    }
                }
            } else {
                List<DynamicField> errorFields = new List<DynamicField>();
                errorFields.add(new DynamicField('Error', 'Error: ' + httpResponse.getStatus()));
                responses.add(errorFields);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            List<DynamicField> exceptionFields = new List<DynamicField>();
            exceptionFields.add(new DynamicField('Exception', e.getMessage()));
            responses.add(exceptionFields);
        }
    }

    return responses;
}

public class APIRequest {
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    public String viewName;

    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    public String id;

    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    public String username;

    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    public String password;
}
}

I am able to use it in Flows and successfully loop through the items in Dynamic Fields. However, I am not able to access individual keys or values during the loop.
All I can do is to work the current item and reference with {!DynamicFieldCollection} but I am not able to do {!DynamicFieldCollection.key} or {!DynamicFieldCollection.value}.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks.
